# RSpec for validating generated object or testing functions?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Below is one of the first RSpec tests I've written, and after implementing it, a few questions were left open to me.

The tests run the same method `calculate` with different inputs, and validate the generated object. However, the individual small methods, like `day_off?` are not explicitly tested.

Should I write tests for the individual methods instead of validating the generated object? Or is it enough to just validate the output? Or should actually both the individual methods and the output be tested?

The typical answer I suppose is "it depends", but depends on what?

I really hope that this won't be closed as a subjective question, because I think there could actually be a useful answer to this.

The complete code can be found at: https://gist.github.com/asmand/d1ccbcd01789353c01c3

Here is the class to be tested:

```
class WeeklyFlexCalculator

  attr_reader :params

  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def calculate
    group_efforts(
      (params.start_date..params.end_date).map do |date|
        daily_effort(date)
      end.compact
    )
  end

  def group_efforts(result)
    weekly = result.group_by { |e| get_week_key(e[:date]) }
    weekly.map do |key,w|
      {
        year: get_year_from_week_key(key),
        week: get_week_from_week_key(key),
        weekTarget: get_target_sum(w),
        weekEffort: get_effort_sum(w),
        efforts: w
      }
    end.sort { |a, b| b.efforts[0].date <=> a.efforts[0].date }
  end

  def daily_effort(date)
      target = get_target(date)
      effort = get_effort(date)
      return if target == 0 && effort == 0
      {
        date: date,
        effort: effort,
        target: target,
        diff: effort - target
      }
  end

  def get_target_sum(efforts)
    efforts.inject(0){|sum,e| sum + e[:target]}
  end

  def get_effort_sum(efforts)
    efforts.inject(0){|sum,e| sum + e[:effort]}
  end

  def get_week_key(date)
    date.cwyear.to_s + "|" + date.cweek.to_s
  end

  def get_year_from_week_key(key)
    key.split('|')[0]
  end

  def get_week_from_week_key(key)
    key.split('|')[1]
  end

  def get_target(date)
    day_off?(date) ? 0 : params.user.hours_per_day
  end

  def get_effort(date)
    ts = get_timesheet(date)
    ts.nil? ? 0.0 : ts.TimeInHours
  end

  def day_off?(date)
    date.wday == 0 or date.wday == 6 or params.holidays.include? date.to_s
  end

  def get_timesheet(date)
    params.timesheets.select {|ts| ts.Date == date.to_s}.first
  end
end
```

And here is the test:

```
require './WeeklyFlexCalculator'

describe WeeklyFlexCalculator, "during Christmas week" do

  subject(:calculation) { WeeklyFlexCalculator.new(params).calculate }

  let(:params) do
    messages = {
      :start_date => Date.new(2013,12,23),
      :end_date => Date.new(2013,12,29),
      :holidays => ["2013-12-24", "2013-12-25", "2013-12-26"],
      :timesheets => [],
      :user => user
    }
    double(:params,messages)
  end

  let(:user) do
    messages = {
      :hours_per_day => 7.5
    }
    double(:user, messages)
  end

  let(:timesheet) do
    messages = {
      :Date => Date.new(2013,12,23).to_s,
      :TimeInHours => 5.0
    }
    double(:timesheet, messages)
  end

  context "with no work performed" do
    it { should have(1).item }

    context "the week calculated" do
      subject(:workweek) {calculation[0]}

      its([:year]) { should eq "2013" }
      its([:week]) { should eq "52" }
      its([:weekTarget]) { should eq 15.0 }
      its([:weekEffort]) { should eq 0.0 }

      context "the work efforts" do
        subject(:efforts) {workweek[:efforts]}

        it { should have(2).items }

        context "the first work effort" do
          subject(:effort) {efforts[0]}

          its([:target]) {should eq 7.5}
          its([:diff]) {should eq -7.5}
          its([:effort]) {should eq 0.0}
        end
      end
    end
  end

  context "with work effort on normal day" do
    before do
      params.stub(:timesheets => [timesheet])
    end

    it { should have(1).item }

    context "the week calculated" do
      subject(:workweek) {calculation[0]}

      its([:year]) { should eq "2013" }
      its([:week]) { should eq "52" }
      its([:weekTarget]) { should eq 15.0 }
      its([:weekEffort]) { should eq 5.0 }

      context "the work efforts" do
        subject(:efforts) {workweek[:efforts]}

        it { should have(2).items }

        context "the first work effort" do
          subject(:effort) {efforts[0]}

          its ([:effort]) { should eq 5.0 }
          its ([:diff]) { should eq -2.5 }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  context "with work effort on a holiday" do
    before do
      timesheet.stub(:Date => Date.new(2013,12,24).to_s)
      params.stub(:timesheets => [timesheet])
    end

    it { should have(1).item }

    context "the week calculated" do
      subject(:workweek) {calculation[0]}

      its([:year]) { should eq "2013" }
      its([:week]) { should eq "52" }
      its([:weekTarget]) { should eq 15.0 }
      its([:weekEffort]) { should eq 5.0 }

      context "the work efforts" do
        subject(:efforts) {workweek[:efforts]}

        it { should have(3).items }

        context "the first work effort" do
          subject(:effort) {efforts[0]}

          its ([:effort]) { should eq 0.0 }
          its ([:diff]) { should eq -7.5 }
        end

        context "the second work effort" do
          subject(:effort) {efforts[1]}

          its ([:effort]) {should eq 5.0}
          its ([:diff]) { should eq 5.0}
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would test them all.  To me, it's comforting knowing that `day_off?` is functionally correct.  If I didn't test that method, I'd always be a little nervous that my tests for `calculate` may be "magically" working simply because of some unknown error in `day_off?`.